# How to convert Python mongongine object (Document) to dictionary?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a collection of object stored in `mongo` which I retrieve with python `mongoengine`. I wish to return a lit of these object in `json` format to an `http` request but it seems IMPOSSIBLE to do. This is the piece of code where I want to return the dictionaries

```
        products = ProductModel.objects()
        products_dict = {}
        try:
            for index, product in enumerate(products):
                products_dict[f"product_{index}"] = product.to_dict()
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        finally:
            return jsonify(products_dict), HTTPStatus.OK
```

and this is my document class:

```
from flask_mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine.fields import (
    StringField,
    DateTimeField,
    FloatField,
    IntField,
)


class ProductModel(Document):
    product_id = StringField(db_field="productId", unique=True)
    product_name = StringField(db_field="productName")
    price = FloatField(db_field="price")
    stock = IntField(db_field="stock")
    description = StringField(db_field="description", required=False)
    animal_type = StringField(db_field="animalType", required=False)
    expiration_date = DateTimeField(db_field="epirationDate", required=False)

    meta = {"indexes": [("product_id"), ("product_name")]}
```

I am sure it cant be that hard how can someone convert these objects to dictionaries I cant find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found these two ways. Python objects made form a class inheriting from mongo `Document`, can be converted:

1. [to json type](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument.to_json) and then be used accordingly
2. [to `SON`](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument.to_json) type and then [to dict](https://api.mongodb.com/python/1.7/api/pymongo/son.html#pymongo.son.SON.to_dict)

Answer (score 2):

You may use `to_mongo()`

```
products = ProductModel.objects()
products.to_mongo()
```

This will give you Python `dict`.